# Bokeh app is running but nothing displays

Tags: python, bokeh

I have this file `bokeh app.py` as follows

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, Slider
from bokeh.models import CategoricalColorMapper
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, gridplot, widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs

x = np.arange(0.3, 10, (10 - 0.3)/300)
y = np.arange(-0.1, 0.1, (0.1 + 0.1)/300)

source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x':x, 'y':y})

plot = figure()
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source)

slider = Slider(title='slider', start=0, end=10, step=0.1, value=1)

def callback(attr, old, new):
    scale = slider.value
    new_y = np.sin(scale/x)
    source.data = {'x': x, 'y': new_y}

# Attach the callback to the 'value' property of slider
slider.on_change('value', callback)   

layout = column(widgetbox(slider), plot)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

In the `anaconda` prompt, I ran this command `bokeh serve "Documents\bokeh app.py"` and the following message appeared in the prompt window

```
2020-03-09 12:20:24,683 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.7 (running on Tornado 4.5.2)
2020-03-09 12:20:24,792 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/bokeh app
2020-03-09 12:20:24,792 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 4360
```

However, there's nothing launch/displayed as expected (please see the screenshot of what should have been shown in my laptop - the screenshot was obtained from DataCamp server output of the same bokeh app.py file). Could someone please explain what's going on? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What does you does the browser JS console say, and the WS protocol ?

Comment: You question is unclear. The screenshot  you show is exactly the expected output. Are you saying that you *aren't* seeing that? FYI you are using ancient versions of both Bokeh and Tornado and would be advised to update both. Your code runs as expected with Bokeh 2.0

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I had to remove the *space* in the file name, that is, renamed the file from `bokeh app.py` to `bokehApp.py`. In anaconda prompt, I used this command `bokeh serve --show bokehApp.py` instead of `bokeh serve "Documents\bokeh app.py"`